# Average deviation of data points from their cluster center changes with each iteration

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

My dataset can be found in kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/vjchoudhary7/customer-segmentation-tutorial-in-python. So i'm running k-means on my dataset that has 4 columns and 200 rows with k = 5. I wanted to find the cluster radius so I measured the average distance of each data point from their respective cluster center but whenever I re-run my program their values change. My cluster centers don't change with each iteration so what's going on exactly? How do I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist


df = pd.read_csv('D:\Mall_Customers.csv', usecols = ['Spending Score (1-100)', 'Annual Income (k$)'])


x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)



kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=100, random_state=0)
y_kmeans= kmeans.fit_predict(x)




centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)



df["cluster"] = kmeans.labels_

n_clusters = 5
clusters = [x[y_kmeans == i] for i in range(n_clusters)]

for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
    print('Cluster {} has {} observations: {}...'.format(i, len(c), c[0]))


df["cluster"] = kmeans.labels_
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)

#cluster radius
def k_mean_distance(data, cx, cy, i_centroid, cluster_labels):
    distances = [np.sqrt((x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2) for (x, y) in data[cluster_labels == i_centroid]]
    return np.mean(distances)

t_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(x)
k_means = KMeans()
clusters = k_means.fit_predict(t_data)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

c_mean_distances = []
for i, (cx, cy) in enumerate(centroids):
    mean_distance = k_mean_distance(t_data, cx, cy, i, clusters)
    c_mean_distances.append(mean_distance)

print("mean distances are", c_mean_distances)
```

Output 1 `[1.5381892556224435, 1.796763983963032, 1.5144402423920744, 3.4372440532366753, 1.6533031213582314]`

Iteration 2 ```[3.180393284279158, 2.809194267986748, 0.7823704675079582, 3.4929008204149365, 1.8109097594336663]

Iteration 3 `[1.9461073260609538, 3.2032294269352155, 2.447917517713439, 3.4372440532366753, 2.197239028470577]`

Comment: Could you show your output. Also, show how your output changes from run to run.

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't include it at first. Output 1```mean distances are [1.9097865683386968, 1.7214300569164354, 2.2666939300276323, 3.4929008204149365, 1.63125643379648]``` , output 2 ```mean distances are [1.9461073260609538, 3.2032294269352155, 2.5364463853472046, 3.4929008204149365, 2.0568592995550845]``` output 3 ```[1.9461073260609538, 0.6032457085536072, 3.2721547114688034, 3.4929008204149365, 2.0568592995550845]```

Comment: I may be missing something. Are you trying to calculate distances after doing KMeans on the PCA tranformation? Is that the output you posted? I think it would help if you updated your question, and posted the output from each print statement. That way we can tell if there is any differences in earlier/later steps. There is no way to reproduce this without your dataset. So it helps greatly to post detailed outputs.

Comment: Yes the above are the outputs, 3 seperate iterations. Updated my post as well with a link to my dataset.

Comment: You have 4 print statements. But you're only showing one output (3 times). Am I correct that this is your last print statement? If so, you haven't specified any parameters the second time you ran kmeans. Could this be the source of some issues?

Comment: Yes you are right that is the last print statement. The other print statements are the cluster centers that stay the same everytime i run it. The second one are the observations labels the third one is a continuation of the second one so that it shows me the whole dataset. And the last one is the one that i am having issues with.

Comment: I really think the second time you run kmeans add parameters like you did the first time. Such as: `k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=100, random_state=0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214126/discussion-between-nippletwister-and-gnodab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add the answer to document the issue.

First, when you are doing a lower dimensional embedding make sure that it doesn't need a random seed to ensure repeatability. In this case (PCA) I think it is ok, but other lower dimensional embedding's may vary.

Second, KMeans does not always converge to a global optima and thus can have varying convergence clusters. To keep KMeans repeatable Scikit Learn has the `random_state` input parameter.

You set this the first time you ran KMeans. This kept the first portion of your code repeatable. To ensure repeatability on the clustering after PCA embedding, set the random state in the same way:

```
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=100, random_state=0)
```